# How do I change the value of the global "$" to a custom function that returns a jQuery instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, global-variables, global, dollar-sign

Before I begin, I'd like to make it clear that ***I don't want to modify the jQuery library in any way***, I just want to replace the value of the `$` global with a custom function that returns a jQuery instance.

In other words, I want the `$` global to not equal jQuery and to return a jQuery instance after it's done doing other (non-jQuery) things.

How do I do this without breaking or modifying the jQuery library?

For example, changing the `$` function so it logs each selector to the console before returning a jQuery instance, using a regular function declaration, like this:

```
function $(selector) {
  console.log(selector);
  return jQuery(selector);
}
```

Results in a tonne of errors like `x is undefined` or `y is used out of scope` being thrown.

After doing some research I've tried putting a `$.noConflict(true)` after the `console.log` function call, like this:

```
function $(selector) {
  console.log(selector);
  $.noConflict();
  return jQuery(selector);
}
```

I got less errors than before but it still doesn't work as expected.

What do I have to change to get my code to work?

Comment: `$.noConflict();` well that only works as long as `$` is jQuery. If it isn't, then you are calling `.noConflict()` on your own function which doesn't have it. Which is why you need to be explicit and do `jQuery.noConflict()` - that way you don't depend on what is currently assigned to `$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting those errors because I wasn't adding jQuery's existing properties and methods to the new `$` function.

I solved the problem by freeing the `$` namespace using `jQuery.noConflict()` and then using `jQuery.extend` to add jQuery's properties and methods the new `$` function before exposing it to the global scope using `window.$ = $`.

Here is the working code:

```
(function() {
  jQuery.noConflict();
  // do stuff...
  var $ = function() {
    // do some more stuff...
    return jQuery.apply(jQuery, arguments);
  };
  // do even more stuff...
  jQuery.extend($, jQuery);
  window.$ = $;
})();
```

I'd also like to thank [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55572957/10415695) and [Archer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55572887/10415695) for their help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery.noConflict()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) to tell jQuery to relinquish control of `$`.

```js
console.log("$ === jQuery", $ === jQuery);

jQuery.noConflict();

console.log("$ === jQuery", $ === jQuery);

$ = function() {
  console.log(...arguments);
  return jQuery(...arguments);
}

$("#ChangeMe").text("We still use jQuery")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="ChangeMe">Text to change</span>
```

This also restores original meaning of `$`, in case you have more than one thing that tries to grab the global variable.

```js
//make the function that uses $ first
$ = function() {
  console.log(...arguments);
  return jQuery(...arguments);
}

//include jQuery
let script = document.createElement('script')

script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js";

script.addEventListener("load", () => {
  console.log("$ === jQuery", $ === jQuery);

  jQuery.noConflict();

  console.log("$ === jQuery", $ === jQuery);

  $("#ChangeMe").text("We still use jQuery")
});

document.body.appendChild(script);
```

```html
<span id="ChangeMe">Text to change</span>
```

If you want to *reassign* the jQuery shorthand, just assign the result of the method call:

```js
j = jQuery.noConflict();

console.log(j === jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a reference to the original value and then using that later, like this...

```
var _$ = $;

function $(selector) {
    console.log(selector);
    return _$(selector);
}
```

If you want to restore everything back to normal at some point later, you can just re-reference the stored value like this...

```
$ = _$;
```

**Note:** The underscore is just my naming convention.  You could call the reference variable anything you like.